# How to get back db_denydatareader and db_denydatawriter

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

In a moment of shear brilliance, i gave my user login on my database (not the db server) on AWS `db_denydatareader` and `db_denydatawriter`

This has obviously caused unlimited problems

This user has access to the rest of the db sever, im wondering what steps i need to take to get these permission back for the particular database

Ive tried accessing the server seucity/logins/user/user mappings

However i get the below dialog, and the database is not showing

[image]

Please note this is an AWS Sql server instance and not a local server

Is there anything i can do to try and re-grant these permission back to that user

Comment: You didn't set up an SA account when you created the instance in RDS?

Comment: unfortunately i didn't set it up, however it may be that ill have to ask the people in charge to give me a log-in to sa or dbsa account

Comment: This solution solved it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749465/master-user-lost-its-permissions-unexpectedly-on-sql-server-rds-instance/48755710#48755710

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to reset your permissions for the master user to the defaults (dbo access in each database), you can reset the master user password from the AWS console and Apply Immediately to have changes take effect.

Here are the steps to do this:

1. Go to the AWS Console
2. Instance Actions -> Modify
3. Under Settings type in a new password for the master password.
4. Select Apply Immediately

Comment: This solution solved it for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749465/master-user-lost-its-permissions-unexpectedly-on-sql-server-rds-instance/48755710#48755710