# AWS SQL Server RDS master user access

Tags: sql-server, permissions, rds

I have created several logins in a SQL Server RDS instance, using the RDS 'master' user to create the logins.  The logins have permissions to create databases.  However, these new databases are inaccessible to the RDS 'master' user.  I receive messages such as:

```
The database xxxxx is not accessible (ObjectExplorer)
```

and

```
The server principal "rdsmaster" is not able to access the database "xxxxx" under the current security context.
```

In order for the RDS master login to have access to these databases, is the only option to have the login that created the database explicitly grant permissions to the new DB?  Or, is there a master switch somewhere that will grant the master login permissions for each new database created, regardless of who created it?  e.g. parameter group, sql role?

I need the master user, or at least a "clone" of the master user, to access all databases for things like index maintenance jobs, backups to S3, etc.

Many thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the master user password in the RDS console worked for me.

Found the solution mentioned in these threads:

- [Master user lost it's permissions unexpectedly on SQL Server (rds instance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48749465/master-user-lost-its-permissions-unexpectedly-on-sql-server-rds-instance#)
- [Granting Access to Database RDS SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064968/granting-access-to-database-rds-sql-server)